# Switch between using ScheduledExecutorService and delay-free File Read

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader, filereader, scheduledexecutorservice

To provide context, I am taking a reasonably long CSV file with one column of values providing the mean daily temperature from 1960-2016 and am reading them with a `BufferedReader` like so:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/dailyTemp.csv")));
```

I also have a Swing Application that provides a `Boolean` value, `slowSpeed`, to declare whether or not the `ScheduledExecutorService` should be ran. i.e. Whether or not it should be slow/fast.

The current purpose of this application is to simply adjust whether the next value read is returned instantly or if it is instead scheduled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    startGraph(); //This is the GUI that provides the state of the slowSpeed variable

    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Main::readFileSlow, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/dailyTemp.csv")));
    String newValue = "";

    while (newValue != null)
    {
        if (slowSpeed)
        {
            newValue = readFileSlow(newValue, br);
        } else
        {
            newValue = readFileFast(newValue, br);
        }
        totalCount++;
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println("FIN");
}

public static String readFileSlow(String newValue, BufferedReader br) throws IOException
{
    while ((newValue = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
    return null;
}

public static String readFileFast(String newValue, BufferedReader br) throws IOException
{
    while ((newValue = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
    return null;
}
```

A necessary consideration is that the `Reader` cannot restart, and therefore the `while` loop exists to check that.

The main issue I am having, is that the `readFileSlow()` function cannot take a variable as therefore it is not a `Runnable` and cannot be controlled by the `ScheduledExecutorService`.

EDIT 1

Here is my primitive version that reasonably shows how it works to switch:

```
public class Main
{
    static Boolean slowSpeed = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        startGraph();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/dailyTemp.csv")));

        String newValue;

        while ((newValue = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (slowSpeed)
            {
                System.out.println(newValue);
                doSomething(newValue);

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            } else
            {
                System.out.println(newValue);
                doSomething(newValue);
            }
            totalCount++;
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("FIN");
    }

    public static void toggleSpeed(Boolean newSpeed)
    {
        slowSpeed = newSpeed;
        System.out.println(slowSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only 20000 datapoints - it would probably be easier to read the file once and store the values in a list.

Comment: @assylias It's just a sample as a proof of concept, but it could be necessary for there to be infinite datapoints and so that can't be done.

Comment: Another option would be to sleep `if (slowSpeed) Thread.sleep(500); newValue = br.readLine();`. You would need to sleep outside the GUI thread of course.

Comment: I started using sleep(), but left that idea as there can be lag. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the `readFileSlow` and `readFileFast` are identical. Let's pretend it's not. The point is to have two methods that could do different things.

Then, let's fix the `readFileSlow` and `readFileFast` a little bit. I'm only showing the `readFileSlow`, the other looks the same:

```
public static void readFileSlow(BufferedReader br) throws IOException
{
    String newValue = null;
    while ((newValue = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(newValue);
        return;
    }
}
```

What happened?

1. There is no return type. If we want to call it from a `ScheduledExecutorService`, then the returned value would be thrown away anyway. The `schedule*` methods don't return `Future` -s to retrieve the results. In case of unscheduled reading, i.e. `executorService.submit()`, we could do something with the return value. But not now.
2. There is no `String newValue` variable. Since that variable is copied at function call (passed-by-value), we can define a local variable with the same name. The result will be the same, but the intent will be easier to understand.

Bear with me, we're almost there.

You can wrap these function calls into lambdas like this:

```
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/dailyTemp.csv")));

    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            readFileSlow(br);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

We need the `try-catch` because `Runnable` is not supposed to throw checked `Exception`-s. `RuntimeException`-s and `Error`-s are okay though.

You can do the same with custom classes that implement `Runnable`:

```
private static abstract class FileReaderTask implements Runnable {

    protected BufferedReader br;

    public FileReaderTask(BufferedReader br) {
        this.br = br;
    }

    protected void doSomethingWithActualLine(String line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}

private static class SlowFileReaderTask extends FileReaderTask {

    public SlowFileReaderTask(BufferedReader br) {
        super(br);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String newValue = null;
            while ((newValue = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                doSomethingWithActualLine(newValue);
                return;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

And then you can schedule them like this:

```
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/dailyTemp.csv")));

    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SlowFileReaderTask(br), 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

There are couple of other options, like replace the `doSomethingWithActualLine()`  method in `FileReaderTask` with a lambda that you give to the constructor. You can choose anything - depending on what you want here to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Taking it further from here, how do I solve switching between reading the file Slowly and reading it immediately?

Comment: How exactly do you want to switch? Why do you want to switch? Just tell me your use-case.

Comment: I've added a primitive version to show the functionality, but with a sleep() call. This is what I'm trying (and failing) to replace.